# Tablelayout addView slows down application

Tags: android, performance, android-tablelayout

I have around `117` `TableRows` which I want to add in the `TableLayout` the issue is it slows down `Activity` launch? I have tried the create the `TableRow` in background and then `publishProgress` chunks of rows so that adding all the rows at the same time may not cause an issue but still I am having a `lag` in the launch. What I have done so far is the following:

```
private class AsyncTaskLoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, CopyOnWriteArrayList<TableRow>, ArrayList<TableRow>> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showProgressDialog();
            tableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(CopyOnWriteArrayList<TableRow>... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            for (TableRow tr : values[0]) {
                tableLayout.addView(tr);
            }
        }
        protected ArrayList<TableRow> doInBackground(Void... params) {


            CopyOnWriteArrayList<TableRow> arr_rows = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
            TableRow row = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < statementSummaryMainReports.size(); i++) {
                StatementSummaryMain report = statementSummaryMainReports.get(i);
                row = printRows(report);
                arr_rows.add(row);
                if(i%25==0) {
                    publishProgress(arr_rows);
                    arr_rows.clear();
                }

            }

            publishProgress(arr_rows);
            return null;
        }



        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TableRow> result) {
            tableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }
```

> How to improve the performance of TableLayout addView so that adding
>   117 TableRows does not slows down Activity

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Creating `117 TableRows` is a very bad design. Because the `TableLayout` with those rows occupies a lot of memory, that is why android provides widgets that use recycling views. You must consider using [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) with **multiple view type**. With this approach only visible views or in other word only necessary views take memory and are drawn. So setup time is going to be very short because only visible views are initializing.

Comment: I know that's the bad design, actually there is a requirement to use the tablelayout.